# I am using python 2.7.13: List comprehension using raw_input wont work:

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension, raw-input

```
D = [d for d in raw_input().split(',')]

print D
```

**This wont print anything and there is no output. Since i am using python 2.7.13, it should work.**

Can someone please what is wrong with it.It just wont run and neither give me any error as well?

Comment: This code works absolutely fine for me. Please explain how you're running your code, what input your typing in, whether the script terminates, etc.

Comment: This is my actual code:

===================

import math

def evaluate_Q():
    C = 50
    H = 30
    Q = []
    D = [d for d in raw_input().split(',')]
    print(D)
    for d in D:
        Q.append(str(int(round(math.sqrt(2*C*(float(d))/H)))))
return ','.join(Q)

print(evaluate_Q())

==================================

Problem is that i wont even get a prompt for user input, which i expect for preparing the list D which has raw_input as you see ,one of the parameters.

Executing the code does nothing.

Wish i could post a video of what is happening

Comment: Please edit your question to include your actual code. (It's fairly unreadable in a comment.)

Comment: What prompt are you expecting? You should just see the program waiting until you type in a line and hit enter. (I tried `1,2,3,4` when I tested, and it worked fine.)

Comment: Extremly sorry...this is my bad
I should have added some user-friendly string as an argument to raw_input() function.Not doing that , i didn't get any prompt and assumed program is stuck and not doing anything

Done that now and it works fine for me as well.

This is really silly of me asking. Should i take the question off SO:( ??